# ImportError using django-social-auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am trying to use django-social-auth to implement google openid login into my app, my problem is that I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /login
Caught ImportError while rendering: cannot import name get_backend
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    #############################
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught ImportError while rendering: cannot import name get_backend
Exception Location: /home/group018/web/WSProject/social_auth/views.py in <module>, line 19
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:
```

At the exception location you can see the hierarchy of my project.

The `view.py` file is as follows:

```
from functools import wraps

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse,HttpResponseServerError
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from WSProject.social_auth.utils import sanitize_redirect, setting, log,backend_setting, clean_partial_pipeline
from WSProject.social_auth.backends import get_backend

DEFAULT_REDIRECT = setting('SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL') or setting('LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL')
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = setting('LOGIN_ERROR_URL', setting('LOGIN_URL'))
RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = setting('SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS', setting('DEBUG'))
PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS = setting('SOCIAL_AUTH_PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS','social_auth.utils.log_exceptions_to_messages')


def dsa_view(redirect_name=None):

.
.
.
```

the function get_backend is defined in `WSProject/social_auth/backends/__init__.py` and I have tried to import it as:

```
from WSProject.social_auth.backends.__init__ import get_backend
```

But it doesn't work... any idea?

Note that the import below to the one I said is working

SOLVED: Finally I did it, the problem was the libraries, they were not correctly installed as jpic said.

Comment: What version of django-social-auth do you have ? How did you install it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
from social_auth.backends import get_backend
```

You should not hardcode the name of your project in your code. That makes the code less portable.

If that doesn't work, then you haven't install django-social-auth correctly. Fix your setup:

1. **Create a virtualenv**, in the parent directory of your project seems fair: `virtualenv /path/to/venv`
2. **Activate the virtualenv**: `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`
3. **Install an app** ie. from git: `pip install -e git+git://github.com/omab/django-social-auth.git#egg=social_auth`

I also wrote a more detailed article on [django, virtualenv and pip](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19725807220/django-pinax-virtualenv-setuptools-pip) which should be of your interrest.

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /login
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named social_auth.backends

Comment: Then django-social-auth is not installed correctly. See my answer update for installation instructions.

Comment: Apparently you downloaded the package and extracted social_auth directory at the root of your project. That's not the correct way to install a python package - you can see the import problems you're having now.

Comment: Actually you are right, I did this:

git clone git://github.com/omab/django-social-auth.git

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)/django-social-auth/

but the problem is that I cannot make sudo in the server because is not mine, is for a project in my university and I don't have permissions, can I do anything else?

Comment: I was in WSProject/ when I did the export

Comment: You can create a project-specific or user-specific virtual environment. You can use it without root permissions it's really cool. See answer update.

Comment: Damn!
The program 'virtualenv' is currently not installed.  To run 'virtualenv' please ask your administrator to install the package 'python-virtualenv'

btw, good article

Comment: Ok, I have permissions on my home directory but no other

Comment: Then create the virtualenv in your home.

Comment: I cannot install virtualenv even in my home, because it writes some other directories /usr/... so I am contacting the administrator, I will post news.

Comment: It's better to install virtualenv globally. But you can also install it locally with --prefix option.

Comment: Finally I could install django-social-auth and openid with
with:

$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/local
$ export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH

but now if I go to INSTALLED_APP in settings.py and I add 'social_auth' and 'openid', the server shows me this:

Unhandled Exception

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

and If take a look to the server log it shows:

Comment: [Mon Mar 05 14:14:00 2012] [warn] [client 80.221.16.179] mod_fcgid: stderr:     app = import_module(appname)
[Mon Mar 05 14:14:00 2012] [warn] [client 80.221.16.179] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Mon Mar 05 14:14:00 2012] [warn] [client 80.221.16.179] mod_fcgid: stderr:     __import__(name)
[Mon Mar 05 14:14:00 2012] [warn] [client 80.221.16.179] mod_fcgid: stderr: TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named openid

Comment: I installed both and it's the same for both applications, the import fails...

How can I write line breaks here? I want to do more readable my posts, but when I post all the line breaks dissapear

Comment: Finally I did it, the problem was the libraries, they were not correclty installed as jpic said.

Comment: @jpic, please update the URL of your article or remove references to it